# java MVC application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

i'm creating an application at the moment that i want to reuse the GUI so to make it easy to reuse and change the elements I've been using the MVC design pattern but im having a few issues with it the first issue is how to implement the actual design pattern as different examples implement it in different ways. this is the code i have in my main, does this look ok.

```
    mainView theView = new mainView();
    mainModel theModel = new mainModel();
    mainController theController = new mainController(theView,theModel);

    theView.setVisible(true);
```

The second problem i have was the example set up was the controller implemented a view in the by using the following code:

controller:

```
    this.theView.addCalculateListener(new CalculateListener());
```

view:

```
public void addCalculateListener(ActionListener listenForCalcButton){
    calculateButton.addActionListener(listenForCalcButton);
}
```

this seems to work fine but i have problems implementing listeners in the JMenu as there added within the constructor of the view so my plan was to create the JMenu in an external class where i can put all the menu items as global variables (to clear up code) which will allow me to add the listeners in this manner, is this an OK solution or am i way off.

Comment: Swing is a form of MVC to begin with (albit M-VC), so trying to put another MVC intop of it is going to cause some issues.  To start with, you should be working with interfaces, which describe a contract between the model-controller-view, so it doesn't matter how those are physically implemented, you can change any one and still have it work.

Comment: IMHO the controller should have no access to the UI components, but instead, should interact through setters/getters and an observer pattern for notifications. This means that the controller doesn't care about how the view is implement, it only cares that the contract is maintained.